# How to autoselect default option on re-render in React MaterialUI Select

Tags: reactjs, select, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm working on a feature where client get's discount when buying a package.
[image]

The item on the left is fixed and doesn't change. It comes in package with the item on the right where client can choose a snowboard:

[image]

All I need is that when client chooses a size, but then swipes to the next snowboard the size chosen from the previous snowboard would be set back to default 'CHOOSE SIZE OPTION'.

Here is the code of the Parent Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Material UI
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/';

// React Responsive Carousel
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import '../../../../../../node_modules/react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css'

// Component
import PackageProd from './PackageProd/packageProd';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    packageCard: {
        maxWidth: 345,
        height: '100%'
    },
});

const Packages = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [defaultProd, setDefaultProd] = useState({ size: 'CHOOSE THE SIZE', discount: '0', price: '0', barcode: 'default' });

    function handleSetProd(val){
        setDefaultProd(val)
    }

    return <Carousel className={classes.packageCard} showIndicators={false}
        renderItem={item => <div style={{ background: "white", height: '100%' }}>{item}</div>}
        onChange={(val)=>{
            setDefaultProd({ size: 'CHOOSE THE SIZE', discount: '0', price: '0', barcode: 'default' })
        }}
    >
        {props._packages.map((prod, i)=>{
            return <PackageProd 
                key={i} 
                _prod={prod} 
                _handleSetProd={handleSetProd}
                _defaultProd={defaultProd}
            ></PackageProd>
        })}
    </Carousel>
}

export default Packages;
```

I'm using a npm package Carousel that comes with an inbuilt method onChange that fires every time you swipe. So it set the defaultProd every time I swipe to the next snowboard or previous one.

Here is the child components:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Material UI
import { makeStyles, Grid, Card, CardContent, CardMedia,
    Typography, CardActions, Button, FormControl, InputLabel,
    Select,  } from '@material-ui/core/';
import { display } from '@material-ui/system';

// React Router
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// Knight Demon
import knightDemon from '../../../../../../assets/icons/knight_demon.png';

// Price Format
const { format } = require('number-currency-format');

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    sizes: {
        minWidth: '100%'
    },
    media: {
        height: '20rem',
        objectFit: 'contain'
    },
    text: {
        color: 'black'
    },
    price: {
        color: 'green'
    },
    redPrice: {
        color: 'red',
        textDecoration: 'line-through'
    },
});

const PackageProd = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [prodDetails, setProdDetails] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        var specificProd = JSON.parse(event.target.value)
        props._handleSetProd(specificProd)
    };

    const PriceWithDiscount = () => <Grid container direction='row' justify='center' spacing={2}>
        <Grid item>
            <span className={classes.redPrice}>
                {format(props._defaultProd.price, {
                    currency: 'isk',
                    showDecimals: 'NEVER',
                    thousandSeparator: ' '
                })}
            </span>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
            <span className={classes.price}>
                {format(Math.ceil(parseInt(props._defaultProd.price) - (parseInt(props._defaultProd.price) * props._defaultProd.discount / 100)), {
                    currency: 'isk',
                    showDecimals: 'NEVER',
                    thousandSeparator: ' '
                })}
            </span>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    const PriceWithoutDiscount = () => <span className={classes.price}>
        {format(props._defaultProd.price, {
            currency: 'isk',
            showDecimals: 'NEVER',
            thousandSeparator: ' '
        })}
    </span>

    return <div>
        <CardMedia
            className={classes.media}
            component='img'
            image={props._prod.images.length > 0 ? props._prod.images[0] : knightDemon}
        />
        <CardContent>
            <Link to={`/product?id=${props._prod._id}`}>
                <Typography className={classes.text} variant='h5' component='h2' onClick={()=>console.log(props._prod)}>
                    {props._prod.description}
                </Typography>
            </Link>
            {props._defaultProd.discount > 0 ?
                <PriceWithDiscount></PriceWithDiscount> :
                <PriceWithoutDiscount></PriceWithoutDiscount>
            }
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
        {props._prod.sizepricesdiscountqty.length >= 1 &&
            props._prod.sizepricesdiscountqty[0].size !== '' ?
            <FormControl className={classes.sizes}>
            <InputLabel htmlFor='age-native-simple'>SIZE</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    native
                    defaultValue={props._defaultProd.size}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    inputProps={{
                        name: 'prodDetails',
                        id: 'age-native-simple',
                    }}
                >
                    <option value={JSON.stringify(props._defaultProd)}>CHOOSE SIZE</option>
                    {props._prod.sizepricesdiscountqty.map((item, i)=>{
                        if(parseInt(item.qty) > 0){
                            return <option key={i}
                                value={JSON.stringify(item)}
                            >
                                {item.size.toUpperCase()}
                            </option>
                        } 
                    })}
                </Select>
            </FormControl> :
            <Grid container justify='flex-start'>
            {props._prod.sizepricesdiscountqty[0].size === '' ?
                <Typography>SIZE: NO SIZE</Typography> :
                <Typography>SIZE: {props._prod.sizepricesdiscountqty[0].size.toUpperCase()}</Typography>
            }
            </Grid>
        }
        </CardActions>
    </div>
}

export default PackageProd;
```

The behaviour which I don't understand is the defaultValue of the Material Select Component. When I log the defaultProd which I pass from the parent it has all the values as it suppose to. When I choose the different size it changes it and sets the defaultProd in the parent to the new object.

Problem is when I swipe to a new product it should change the defaultValue to size value of defaultProd but it doesn't. Changes are reflected in price, console logs the defaultProd correctly, but size doesn't change to 'CHOOSE SIZE' and I have no idea why it doesn't reflect the change as it should. Here is the visual example:

1. I choose the size and the changes are reflect both in price and the size and I successfully log the change:
   [image]

[image]

But then I swipe to the next snowboard and swipe back to the previous one. Price reflect the change. defaultProd is logged correctly, but size doesn't change:
[image]

[image]

What I tried so far was to try and force the re-render with:

```
const [, updateState] = useState();
const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);
```

and fire them inside useEffect() in child component. I tried using `value` instead of `defaultValue` but when changing the size it wouldn't work and would just show `CHOOSE SIZE` all the time. At this point I don't understand how defaultValue in material Select works and why it doesn't reflect changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In child component I changed `defaultValue` to `value` in Select, deleted `native` and used `renderValue` function. So my child component code in Select looks like this:

```
<Select
   value={JSON.stringify(props._defaultProd)}
   renderValue={(val)=>JSON.parse(val).size}
   onChange={handleChange}
>
   <option disabled value={JSON.stringify(props._defaultProd)}>CHOOSE SIZE</option>
   {props._prod.sizepricesdiscountqty.map((item, i)=>{
      if(parseInt(item.qty) > 0){
         return <option key={i}
            value={JSON.stringify(item)}
         >
            {item.size.toUpperCase()}
         </option>
      } 
   })}
</Select>
```

Now the value is being reflected on rerendering.